# Run JVM unit test as an Android instrumented test

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

I added unit tests (that run on bare JVM) to a Kotlin library, and I'd like to also run the code in ART (Android Runtime) and Dalvik VM against the Android API, reusing the defined tests in the `test` sourceSet, and running them with tests in the `androidTest` sourceSet, on a real device or in an emulator.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

The reason why I want to do this is that I run some code on the main thread when on a real device, falling back to a custom thread if an error/exception is thrown because not running on a real device, but I also want to test the code when it doesn't fallback because it is running on a real device which has access to the main thread.

Comment: this might defeat the idea of unit vs. instrumented tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, move the JVM tests from 'test' directory to androidTest target. It runs the JVM tests along with instrumentation tests.